# The hotkey "dp"(diff put) has a mapping conflict with vim-fugitive, when copying changes with vimdiff

Tags: vim, vimdiff, vim-fugitive

When comparing files, I like to use `vimdiff`(or `vim -d`) and I know a recommended way of copying changes with vimdiff is:

```
]c               - advance to the next block with differences
[c               - reverse search for the previous block with differences
do (diff obtain) - bring changes from the other file to the current file
dp (diff put)    - send changes from the current file to the other file
```

and I also know that

- `:diffget` is the same as `do`
- `:diffput` is the same as `dp`

All these commands work perfectly (including`:diffput`), but when I input `dp`, nothing changes and an error sound is produced.

I think this is because of a hotkey mapping conflict with vim-fugitive, which has a hotkey `dp`:

```
dp    :Git! diff (p for patch; use :Gw to apply)
dp    :Git add --intent-to-add (untracked files)
```

How to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: fugitive's `dp` works in preview window, however diff's `dp` is for diff mode,  do they have conflict?   btw, your logo picture is exactly same as mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still invoke the built-in mapping via `:normal! dp`.

If you need this multiple times, better undefine the original buffer-local mapping:

```
:nunmap <buffer> dp
```

However, as @Kent has commented, fugitive's `dp` mapping is only active in a *preview window* (cp. `:h fugitive-:Gstatus`). Since you should use normal windows for diffing and merging, there shouldn't be an overlap.

Comment: `:nunmap <buffer> dp` can't not work:
E31: No such mapping

Comment: I feel sorry. Input `:nunmap <buffer> dp`, then output: `E31: No such mapping'。
Actually, I can't find dp in `nmap`.

I agree what you say about :" fugitive's dp mapping is only active in a preview window (cp. :h fugitive-:Gstatus). "

What's more, when startup vim without .vimrc or pluggings -- `vim -u NONE -N`, `dp`command works perfectly.

So, what could I do next step?

Comment: I feel sorry. Input `:nunmap <buffer> dp`, then output: `E31: No such mapping`。
Actually, I can't find dp in `nmap`.

I agree what you say about :" fugitive's dp mapping is only active in a preview window (cp. :h fugitive-:Gstatus). "

What's more, when startup vim without .vimrc or pluggings -- `vim -u NONE -N`, `dp`command works perfectly.

Comment: You have to execute the `:nunmap <buffer> dp` in the fugitive buffer that was opened via `:Gstatus` (so this shows a Git status, and has filetype GITCOMMIT), as the mapping is only defined there. If the command causes `E31: No such mapping`, then the built-in `dp` should work just fine, no problem there.

Comment: Your conclusion is helpful.
As causes `E31: No such mapping`, I think `dp` had been **unmap** by an unknow plugin, than **remap**.
Therefor, I put this in .vimrc: `nnoremap dp :diffput<CR>`. It works well.
How ever, I don't know which plugin should be blamed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. My error was that `map p` maps p also in operator-pending mode. You can try to do a `ounmap p`. In my case, it was related to the [miniyank plugin](https://github.com/bfredl/nvim-miniyank/issues/8)